# How to set back button on toolbar to do the same thing as system back button?

Tags: android, user-interface, back-button, titlebar

In my main activity i have ViewPager and on my second page i have CardView, when i click on CardView, it opens new activity with some info. Problem is when i want to go back, if i click back button in toolbar it goes back to main activity but ViewPager is set on first page (not the second one where CardView was). However, when i click back on my system button it goes correctly to main activity on second page.

This is how i open new activity when i click on CardView

```java
adapter.setListener(new CaptionedImagesAdapter.Listener(){
           public void onClick(int pos){
               Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
PizzaDetailActivity.class);
               intent.putExtra(PizzaDetailActivity.EXTRA_PIZZA_ID, pos);
               getActivity().startActivity(intent);
           }
});
```

Setting Up (back) button in toolbar

```java
Toolbar tb = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(tb);
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

And i placed MainActivity as parent in Manifest

```xml
<activity
android:name=".OrderActivity"
android:label="@string/label_porudzbina"
android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
```